# Insertar archivos CSS

Tags: php, css, html5

Estimados he creado un formulario.php pero al llamar a el archivo css no reconoce los estilos,por favor me pueden ayudar, gracias.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">

</head>

<body>
```

Comment: Estas seguro que la ruta es la correcta? que error te tira por consola de tu navegador?

Comment: Muestranos el error que te sale

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera en localhost reconoce al formulario pero no a los estilos aplicados al formulario.php, ya que este mismo estilo estoy ocupando en otros formularios.html, en donde sí los reconoce estimado.

Comment: @Santiago estimado al mostrar el formulario.php me indica todo el contenido pero sin los estilos a los que estoy llamando.

Comment: Envia la ruta donde esta el archivo css y donde esta el archivo formulario, tambien envia el codigo del archivo css para verificiar su codigo

Comment: tal vez pueda ser el llamado a las clases de las etiquetas, tendrías que mostrarnos un poco mas de la informacion. la etiquetas que hacen uso de el .css y las rutas donde estan guardados los archivos.

Comment: Abre el archivo de los estilos en el navegador

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

 <meta name="viewport"    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 <meta name="author"      content="Consorcio Sur Occidental">
 
 <title>Flota Operativa</title>

 
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"> ARCHIVO CSS QUE NO RECONOCE EL FORMULARIO.php

</head>

Comment: Quizás te falta una barra antes de css/estilos.css >> /css/estilos.css

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba si en la consola, en la pestaña de red, te devuelve un código 200.
Si es así es que se ha cargado bien el fichero.
Si recibes un código 404 es que el fichero no se ha cargado y posiblemente sea lo que comenta Miquel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [answer].   intenta dar una solución de código. Un saludo